# LIKE statement with Table variable

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a `SELECT`statement using values I have in a table variable.

```
declare @emailids   TABLE (usrmst_id INT)
declare @actionids  TABLE (tskmst_id INT)

insert into @emailids (usrmst_id)
    select usrmst_id 
    from usrmst 
    where usrmst_domain = 'EMAIL'

insert into @actionids (tskmst_id)
    select tm.tskmst_id 
    from tskmst tm
    inner join tskmail tml 
        on tml.tskmail_id = tm.tskmst_id
    where 
        tskmail_to_int like '%' + (select cast(usrmst_id as CHAR(5)) from @emailids) + '%'

select * from @actionids
```

This is obviously failing because the `select cast(usrmst_id as CHAR(5)) from @emailids` has multiple results. What I want to do is for each value in the `@emailids` table to generate a return into the `@actionids` table.

Comment: Do you try? select DISTINCT usrmst_id from usrmst where usrmst_domain = 'EMAIL'

Comment: @Beto - there's only one usrmst_id for each value with the domain 'EMAIL' so I don't need to do a DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
insert into @actionids (tskmst_id)
    select tm.tskmst_id 
    from tskmst tm
    inner join tskmail tml 
        on tml.tskmail_id = tm.tskmst_id
    inner join @emailids e
        on tskmail_to_int like '%' + cast(e.usrmst_id as varchar(5)) + '%'
```

---

You should `CAST` to `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`. I believe casting to `CHAR` pads the strings with spaces until it reaches the defined length. So when you `CAST` 60 to `CHAR(5)`, it becomes `60[space][space][space]`.

Comment: This isn't giving me a failure however it's not returning any values and it should be.  I'm trying to understand why that is.  If I change the last line to this - `on tskmail_to_int like '%' + '60' + '%'` which is one of the values in @emailids it does return a value for each value in the table (same value obviously) but it's not doing it in the code you've put.

Comment: Try casting to `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.